# Which jQuery selector is more efficient with .find()

Tags: jquery

Does the tag name hurt or help?

1) `$content.find('[name=foo]')`

or

2) `$content.find('input[name=foo]')`

Comment: Try it and see: http://www.jsperf.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I wrote a quick JSPerf test](http://bit.ly/1wgcsdM), it's actually almost the same.

Both are pretty slow (jQuery is quite slow anyway).

[I tested the $.find() method two weeks ago](http://bit.ly/1n57qex).  It's a good habit to use it, it's pretty efficient.

Comment: It would be interesting if you can make the html a little more complex to see if the difference is higher

Comment: Yes, good point. It's still really simple. The difference is computed in % anyway.

Comment: correct, but I imagine that a complex DOM should impact on the result, making the difference even more evident. In your example, basically all elements match the "input" selector, you should add different tags.

Comment: Ok, got the point. Well, feel free to try. But I think the difference won't be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Before testing it, I'd say the second should perform better since it can take advantage of DOM method `getElementsByTagName`. This is a first level filter that should improve a little the performance.

Probably it won't be noticiable unless the page is complex enough

Comment: that's what I initially thought. does jQuery use that DOM method if the tag is passed on a .find()?

Comment: if you look at the jquery code, the method `getElementsByTagName` is used by jquery to resolve tag selectors as long the method is available on the browser.